# Can I install SW in Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am in the process of renting an Amazon EC2 instance. I need to install some libraries to run my code. For example I need OpenSSL library. Can I install SW in the instance? Will I get root access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you get full access and you can do with it what you want, just like it was sitting on your desk.